# Google Sign In for iOS: Setting a custom language doesn't work, when using latest SDK v5.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-signin

I'm using Google Sign In for iOS, with the latest SDK version 5.0.1 (added manually):
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk

`GIDSignIn` provides an interface for setting the language for sign in, as is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn#language

The only constraint seems that setting to a custom language (in the form of ISO 639-1) needs to be done **before** calling the `signIn` method.

However, this doesn't seem to work for me - i.e setting to a custom language doesn't result in the sign in web form to be shown in the requested language.

Attaching a snippet of a custom handler we use, where I set the language to Italian, but the sign in form is still shown in English.

```
@objc public class MGGoogleAuthHandler: NSObject, GIDSignInDelegate {
    // MARK: Properties
    @objc public static var shared = MGGoogleAuthHandler()


    // MARK: Life Cycle
    public override init() {
        super.init()
        setup()
    }
}
```

```
private extension MGGoogleAuthHandler {
    func setup() {
        gid.delegate = self
        gid.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
        gid.language = "it" // HERE I SET THE LANGUAGE TO ITALIAN
    }
```

Usage:

```
MGGoogleAuthHandler.shared.signInUser...
```